# Distance between two points in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to write distance between two points in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Let $P=(z_1,z_2)$ And $Q=(w_1,w_2)$ be two points in $\mathbb{C}^2$. What is the expression for the distance between these two points?
Maybe this is a silly question. But unable to find.

Comment: What is the distance between two points in $\mathbb C ?$ Can you generalize that to $\mathbb C^2$?

Comment: $|z-w|$, For $\mathbb{C}^2$ distance is $√{(|z_1-w_1|^2+|z_2-w_2|^2)}$. Is this okay?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In fact, this can also be generalized to $\mathbb C^{\,n}$ in this natural way.

Comment: Okay thank you.